# deploying new profile

Tags: change-set, custom-profile

I've created a new profile in Sandbox and want to deploy into production with the help of change set. I can add the profile in change set through "Add Profile" option in "Profile Settings For Included Components" section but unable to upload the change set as the option for upload is grade out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deploy a profile by itself via change sets. Doing so would render the profile completely useless in a new org. This is because things like field level security, object level security, Visualforce page access, and Apex Class access requires those elements to be included in the change set. You'll need to either add all of the elements in your org to ensure that no permissions are missed, or use the Force.com IDE to fully retrieve the profile so you can deploy it.

See [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206563&type=1&language=en_US) for more info.

> It's not possible to upload a change set containing only profiles so you'll need to make sure that a component is also included. Profiles are not officially supported as individual components in change sets as per the Components Available in Change Sets documentation. Although profiles are available and can be selected with other components, there are limitations on what specific parts of the profile's permissions can be deployed via change sets.

Comment: How is field-level security shared through a changeset?

Comment: @jbyrd you must deploy the profile and the fields, and the field level security will be included automatically for the matrix of profiles and fields selected.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your profile has "Deploy Change Sets" & "Create and Upload Change Sets" enabled in your Administrative Permissions section.

**P.S** - I agree with @SfdcFox's answer. Refrain urself from deploying profile through change set.It wont do anything good for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need deploy profile with your custom settings (field level security, object security and other) you should push it with all of object, fields and other component. When you deploy profile without this component - you hadn't your custom settings.